# Uploading file with separated lines in tornado from an HTML template

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

I'm trying to create a function for uploading files from a web page (RequestHandler + HTML) with tornado.

I found a way to do it with this code. But the problem is that the whole content of the file is wrote in a single line which is normal because the function self.request.files saves the content of the file in a dictionary.

python code:

```
def post(self):
    myfile = self.request.files['file1'][0]
    print("myfile is", myfile)
    fname = myfile['filename']
    upload_file = open("./some_files/%s" % fname, 'w')
    upload_file.write(str(myfile['body']))
```

html code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/build" method="post">
  File: <input type="file" name="file1" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

So how can I separate the lines of my uploaded file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the fact that the content of the file was in binary format and I transformed it to string with `str()`. The correct way was to use `decode()` like this

```
def post(self):
    myfile = self.request.files['file1'][0]
    fname = myfile['filename']
    file_content = myfile['body'].decode("utf-8")
    print(file_content)
    with open("./some_files/%s" % fname, 'w') as upload_file:
        upload_file.write(file_content)
```